# Common passive forms - 'foot was hurt' versus 'foot got hurt'

Tags: style, passive-voice

As you obviously know, We face a lot of situations that we need to use a passive form of a sentence, but I was wondering which one of the following forms could be both common and accurate.

For instance:

1. My foot was hurt when I was playing football.
2. My foot got hurt when I was playing football.

I was thinking to myself, the second one must convey the meaning with more detail, like when I was playing football, my foot got hurt by someone/something.
And the first one is a bit general.

Now what I'm trying to realize is summarized by the two following questions:

1. What is the point of view which each one carries the meaning with?
2. Which one of the forms is more common in daily English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say both of them are common and accurate. To be and to get have different nuance and meaning even though both of them could be used in the passive voice as in your example. The former emphasizes the state of the subject and the latter puts more focus on the action or process of the action.

The linked [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/get-passive) explains you use get-passive:

> 1. Especially in informal speaking. When we use the get passive, we also place a little more emphasis on the **nature of the action** itself
>      or on the person involved in the action: '*I’ve got good news for you. Jim finally **got** promoted.*'

or

> 2. In speaking of events that are **negative** or **not desired**: '*Our car got stolen last night.*'

Which one to use largely depends on what you try to mean and you need to **get** yourself familiarized with the differences reading many example sentences. If you want the state to be emphasized, use "be-passive" and if you want the action to be emphasized, use "get-passive".

You can get more references such as [this](http://www.grammaring.com/the-passive-with-get) if you Google "get passive".

Comment: That was informative enough to get a point. Thanks.

Comment: @DevinHudson My pleasure. .

Comment: RE: _The former (to be) emphasizes the state of the subject and the latter (to get) puts more focus on the action or process of the action._ This is subtle but true. For example: in _Her car was stolen_ vs. _Her car got stolen_, and _I had the measles_ vs. _I got the measles_, the latter emphasizes the action (the stealing of the car, the catching of the disease) just a little bit more.