# Should 'got' be used instead of 'was' in formal reports?

Tags: past-tense, formality

I frequently write reports for customers with detailed descriptions of my work. Neither me nor my colleagues are native speakers but they frequently use 'got', where I would rather use 'was'. Very crude examples:

- The file got deleted.
- The parcel got delivered.

I've corrected this numerous times, but my colleagues do not understand my issue with the term. I've googled, but could not come up with a proper rule against the use of 'got' in these scenarios.

To me, 'got' *feels* too informal or colloquial to be used in our reports. Do I have any grounds for this accusation or is it purely subjective?

Our reports are US English, but I'd be interested in any rules concerning the topic for both US and UK English.

Comment: 'Correct' English would use _was_ in both cases.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, apparently the issue rattled my brain. I'll adjust the question!

Comment: You haven't indicated whether you are using US or UK English. The acceptability  of *got* is quite different between them.

Comment: I was not aware that there would be a difference in this case. I've learned UK English in school and uni, but we base our reports more on US English.

Comment: You might find the answers to [Common passive forms - 'foot was hurt' versus 'foot got hurt'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/87835/9161) helpful, but I don't think it fully answers this question.

Comment: @ColleenV yes, thank you for the additional reference!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We should use **was** in both cases in formal writing.

[**get** in Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/get) sense 17 is stated as informal:

> 17. (auxiliary, **informal**) Used with the past participle to form the dynamic passive voice of a dynamic verb. Compared with static passive with **to be**, this emphasizes the commencement of an action or entry into a state.
>     Synonym: **to be**

> He **got** bitten by a dog.

Some other dictionaries also have general statements on **get** being fairly informal.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get) has this note at the beginning of its definition of **get**:

> LANGUAGE NOTE:

> In most of its uses **get** is a fairly informal word.

[Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get) has this note after its sense 27 definition:

> Get is one of the most common words in English, but some people try to avoid it in formal writing.